# Type mismatch in key from map even though i setMapOutputKey class

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, typeerror

I am getting type mismatch from map even though i have set map output key class and map output value class.
This is my sample code.

```
public class NgramCount{
  protected final static String RAWCOUNTDIR = "raw−counts";
  public static class countMap extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable (1) ;

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) 
    throws IOException {
        String line = value.toString();
        output.collect(value,one);
    }
  }
  public static class countReduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
    throws IOException{
        int sum = 0;
        while(values.hasNext()) {
            sum += values.next().get();
        }
        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job jobA = new Job(conf);
    jobA.setJarByClass(NgramCount.class);
    jobA.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    // the values are counts(ints)
    jobA.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    jobA.setMapperClass(NgramCount.countMap.class);
    jobA.setReducerClass(NgramCount.countReduce.class);

    jobA.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    jobA.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(jobA, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(jobA, new Path(RAWCOUNTDIR));
    jobA.waitForCompletion(true);
    System.out.println("Job1 finished.");
  }
}
```

This is the error I am receiving.

```
15/01/17 14:16:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1421481783919_0005_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1050)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:691)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:124)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
```

Please help me. I am stuck here

Comment: are you sure you are running an up-to-date jar and not a previous one? Which version of hadoop do you have? Check that your code is compatible with the version of hadoop that you have.

Answer (score 0):

In your map and reduce functions you are confounding the use of key types: For example you tell you mapper to send an output of this signature (LongWritable key, Text value) while you write output.collect(value,one) in which value is of type Text and not of type LongWritable.

Answer (score 0):

Your mapper code is not right.. you should write Text key.. which is not getting written.

```
private Text word = new Text();
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) 
throws IOException {
    String line = value.toString();
    word.set(line);
    output.collect(value,one);

}
```